# Strange behavior with File object and = in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm having a very strange behavior in my application, for some reason when I do:

```
data.count
```

It will return the correct amount of entries (234). However when I do this:

```
other_data = data
other_data.count
```

It returns 0, which is incorrect.

Here is my code (data is a method):

```
  def data
    begin
      file = open(url)
    rescue OpenURI::HTTPError => e
      self.update_column(:failed_at, Time.now)
      []
    end
  end
```

Also, when debugging with this code:

```
puts "data: #{data}"
puts "other_data: #{other_data}"
```

I get:

```
data: #<File:0x007fbe7beef7c8>
other_data: #<File:0x007fbe7a1707b0>
```

Note the memory addresses are different.

Any ideas how I could get a reference to data that will return the correct count and allow me to access the object's other methods? (such as each_with_index - which also works for data but not other_data)

Comment: Why do you assign the result of `open(url)` to the `file` variable but then never use the `file` variable? And in your `rescue` block why do you return an empty array? It doesn't make sense to return a File object sometimes and an Array other times. At any rate, your method (when it doesn't enter the `rescue` block) is going to return a new File object each time, which is why `other_data = data` yields a different object than `data` does when you call it a second time.

Comment: That makes sense, but still doesn't explain the different behavior for the file by calling data vs other data. I agree the method could be written better but this is code that I inherited. Any ideas how to structure this so that when I call either method I get the same result?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Show a minimal example of your code and explain why it doesn't work for you. See "[ask]".

Answer (score 0):

While I was not able to reproduce your problem, I believe you have some scoping issues or are accidentally calling `count` on the same instance twice.

The `count` method count the response size of the returned file (webpage) then moves the read pointer to the end of the file. [(Read about IO pointers and `seek` here)](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/IO.html#method-i-seek)

```
2.2.1 :002 > file = open('http://www.google.com')
 => #<Tempfile:/var/folders/my/l9cxzl7j3vs8cy9vqy0jzfvc0000gp/T/open-uri20151012-93142-387w2p> 
2.2.1 :003 > file.count
 => 25 
2.2.1 :004 > file.count
 => 0
```

I bet somewhere in your code `other_data`called `count` and then you saw the unexpected behvaiour. I would try and make sure that nothing like that is occuring.